# ReactJS Simple User Information Feature Implementation Not Working

Tags: reactjs, request, components, jsx, response

I am working on a simple React program as a team project for practice. I am in charge of the frontend part and am developing the login-related features. Among them, I have created the code for updating user information as follows, but there is still a problem with the backend, making it difficult to identify where the problem lies in my code. Please let me know if there is an issue with the feature implementation.

The client sends CRUD requests to Firebase to obtain a JWT token, which is then sent to the NestJS server in order to authenticate the user by providing a cookie.and we use proxy.

**api information**

- [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4g89g.png)
- { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }

**get !!!**

- http status codes:
  200 OK // Login status verification complete
  400 Bad Request // wrong format
  401 Unauthorized // Non-authentication (authentication information not provided)
  403 Forbidden // No access (I know who the client is)
  500 Internal Server Error // server problem
- example response:

  ```
  {
      error: null | { statusCode: 401, message: “Unauthorized”  } 
      data: {
          username: ‘vision’
          email: ‘test03@test.com’
      }
  }
  ```
- response schema :

  ```
  {
      error: null | { statusCode: number Required , message: string Required } 
      data: {
          username: string Required
          email: string Required  
      }
  }
  ```
- note :
  Through a cookie sent by the client in the backend
  check the uid value in the session with the session ID value of the cookie.
  Email to firebase-admin should be imported through firebase as uid as a factor. (getUser())

**put !!!**

- http status codes:
  201 Created // Sign up complete
  400 Bad Request // wrong format
  500 Internal Server Error // server problem
- example request:

  ```
  {
      “uid”: “Va0vxN71xKVWZKtFWTtIAPNsSgt1”,
      “username”: “vision”,
  }
  ```
- request schema :

  ```
  {
      uid: string Required
      username: string Required
  }
  ```
- example response:

  ```
  {
      error: null | { statusCode: 401, message: “Unauthorized”  } 
      data: null
  }
  ```
- note :
  username (Nickname) - 2 to 10 characters in length
  email - conforms to email format
  password - at least 6 characters in length and no more than 18 characters at the front

  Register email and password to auth with Firebase (createUserWithEmailAndPassword())
  receive function return value and extract uid,
  Signing out of Firebase using auth.signOut()
  In case of creation or failure, Firebase registration must be canceled on backend request,
  uid and nickname are stored in DB

**delete !!!**

- http status codes:
  200 OK // Delete complete
  400 Bad Request // Invalid format
  401 Unauthorized // Unauthorized (Authentication information not provided)
  403 Forbidden // No access (we know who the client is)
  404 Not Found // Nothing to delete
  500 Internal Server Error // Server problem
- example response:

  ```
  {
      error: null | { statusCode: 400, message: “Bad Request”  } 
      data: null
  }
  ```
- response schema :

  ```
  {
      error: null | { statusCode: number Required , message: string Required } 
      data: null
  }
  ```
- note :
  At the front when deleting, a confirmation modal window or warning window is required (no password
  confirmation)
  After logging out, it is displayed as a deletion completion page, modal window, warning window, etc.

  In the backend identify uid on backend server through session ID of cookie, delete on Firebase
  (deleteUser())
  Delete related information by uid from DB ()

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import { getAuth, deleteUser } from 'firebase/auth';

import styles from './AccountsCompo.module.scss';

function AccountsCompo({ isLogin }) {
    const [formState, setFormState] = useState({
        username: { value: '', valid: false, message: '', touched: false },
        email: { value: '', valid: false, message: '', touched: false },
        password: { value: '', valid: false, message: '', touched: false },
        passwordConfirm: { value: '', valid: false, message: '', touched: false },
    });

    // Save user original information
    const [originalState, setOriginalState] = useState(null);

    const navigate = useNavigate();

    useEffect(() => {
        if (isLogin) {
            navigate('/');
        }
    }, [isLogin, navigate]);

    // GET: Request to receive member information (before entering input): No password
    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchAccountInfo = async () => {
            try {
                const response = await fetch('/api/v1/accounts', {
                    method: 'GET',
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    },
                    //credentials: 'include',
                });

                if (!response.ok) {
                    console.log('Error getting account information');
                    return;
                }

                const data = await response.json();

                if (response.status === 200 && data && data.data) {
                    const { username, email } = data.data;
                    const newState = {
                        username: { value: username, valid: true, touched: true },
                        email: { value: email, valid: true, touched: true },
                    };
                    console.log(username, email);

                    // Change user information
                    setFormState(newState);
                    setOriginalState(newState);
                } else {
                    console.error(`Error: ${data.error.message}`);
                }
            } catch (error) {
                console.log('Member information retrieval request failed', error);
            }
        };

        fetchAccountInfo();
    }, []);

    // Update value on input, validation
    const onChange = (e) => {
        const {
            target: { name, value },
        } = e;

        //Define newState based on previous state of formState
        setFormState((prevState) => {
            const newState = {
                ...prevState[name],
                value: value,
                touched: true,
                edited: true,
            };

            // Check if your nickname is 3-10 characters long (before pressing the signup button)
            if (name === 'username') {
                if (value.length < 3 || value.length > 10) {
                    newState.message = 'Nicknames must be at least 3 characters and no more than 10 characters.';
                    newState.valid = false;
                } else {
                    newState.message = 'A valid nickname.';
                    newState.valid = true;
                }
            }

            if (name === 'email') {
                const emailRegex = /^[a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6}$/;
                if (!emailRegex.test(value)) {
                    newState.message = 'Please enter a valid email.';
                    newState.valid = false;
                } else {
                    newState.message = 'This is a valid email.';
                    newState.valid = true;
                }
            }

            // Check whether the password contains a nickname or email address and is within 6 to 16 characters (before pressing the sign up button)
            if (name === 'password') {
                const containsNumber = /\d/.test(value);
                const containsCharacter = /[a-zA-Z]/.test(value);
                const containsSpecialCharacter = /\W/.test(value);
                const countValidations = [
                    containsNumber,
                    containsCharacter,
                    containsSpecialCharacter,
                ].filter(Boolean).length;

                if (value.length < 6 || value.length > 16 || countValidations < 2) {
                    newState.message =
                        'The password must be at least 6 characters and not more than 16 characters, and cannot contain a nickname or email. It must also contain at least two of numbers, letters, and special characters.';
                    newState.valid = false;
                } else {
                    newState.message = 'A valid password.';
                    newState.valid = true;
                }
            }

            if (name === 'passwordConfirm') {
                if (value !== formState.password.value) {
                    newState.message = 'Passwords do not match.';
                    newState.valid = false;
                } else {
                    newState.message = 'Passwords match.';
                    newState.valid = true;
                }
            }   

            return { ...prevState, [name]: newState };
        });
    };

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //////////// Buttons: edit information, cancel, opt out
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    const onSubmit = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        const isFormValid = Object.values(formState).every((field) => field.valid);
        if (!isFormValid) {
            return;
        }

        const auth = getAuth();
        const user = auth.currentUser;
        if (!user) {
            console.log('There are currently no users logged in.');
            return;
        }

        try {
            const response = await fetch('/api/v1/accounts', {
                method: 'PUT',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                },
                body: JSON.stringify({
                    username: formState.username.value,
                    email: formState.email.value,
                    password: formState.password.value,
                }),
                credentials: 'include',
            });

            if (!response.ok) {
                throw new Error('Error updating account information');
            }

            const data = await response.json();

            if (response.status === 200 && data && data.data) {
                // Logout processing when password is changed: Logout API must be used, change islogin
                if (formState.password.value !== '') {
                    console.log('Your password has been changed. Please log in again.');
                    navigate('/login');
                } else {
                    console.log('Member withdrawal success');
                }
            } else {
                console.error(`Error: ${data.error.message}`);
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.log('Member withdrawal request failed', error);
        }
    };

    const CancelAccountChange = () => {
        if (originalState) {
            setFormState(originalState);
            console.log('cancel edit');
        }
    };

    const DeleteAccount = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log('Delete pressed');
    
        const auth = getAuth();
        const user = auth.currentUser;
        if (!user) {
            console.log('There are currently no users logged in.');
            return;
        }

        try {
            const response = await fetch('/api/v1/accounts', {
                method: 'DELETE',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                },
            });

            if (!response.ok) {
                throw new Error('Error deleting account');
            }

            const data = await response.json();

            if (response.status === 200 && data && data.data) {
                console.log('Member withdrawal success');
            } else {
                throw new Error(`Error: ${data.error.message}`);
            }
      
            await deleteUser(user);

            setFormState({
                username: { value: '', valid: false, message: '', touched: false },
                email: { value: '', valid: false, message: '', touched: false },
                password: { value: '', valid: false, message: '', touched: false },
                passwordConfirm: {
                    value: '',
                    valid: false,
                    message: '',
                    touched: false,
                },
            });
            setOriginalState(null);
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Member withdrawal request failed', error);
        }

    };

    return (
        <>
            <div className={styles.container}>
                <div className={styles.title}>my page</div>

                <form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
                    <div>
                        <input
                            name="username"
                            type="text"
                            placeholder="username"
                            value={formState.username.value}
                            onChange={onChange}
                            required
                            className={styles.inputBox}
                        />
                    </div>
                    <div>{formState.username.touched && formState.username.message}</div>

                    <div>
                        <input
                            name="email"
                            type="text"
                            placeholder="email"
                            value={formState.email.value}
                            onChange={onChange}
                            required
                            className={styles.inputBox}
                        />
                    </div>
                    <div>{formState.email.touched && formState.email.message}</div>
                    {console.log(formState.password)}
                    <div>
                        <input
                            name="password"
                            type="password"
                            placeholder="password"
                            value={formState.password.value}
                            onChange={onChange}
                            required
                            className={styles.inputBox}
                        />

                        <div>
                            {formState.password.touched && formState.password.message}
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div>
                        <input
                            name="passwordConfirm"
                            type="password"
                            placeholder="passwordConfirm"
                            className={styles.inputBox}
                            value={formState.passwordConfirm.value}
                            onChange={onChange}
                            required
                        />
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        {formState.passwordConfirm.touched && formState.passwordConfirm.message}
                    </div>

                    <div>
                        <input
                            type="submit"
                            value="Modifications completed"
                            onClick={onSubmit}
                            className={styles.registerBtn}
                            disabled={!Object.values(formState).every((field) => field.valid)}
                        />
                    </div>

                    <div>
                        <input
                            type="submit"
                            value="cancel"
                            onClick={CancelAccountChange}
                            className={styles.registerBtn}
                            disabled={
                                !formState.username.valid ||
                                !formState.email.valid ||
                                !formState.password.valid ||
                                !formState.passwordConfirm.valid
                            }
                        />
                    </div>

                    <div>
                        <input
                            type="submit"
                            value="withdraw"
                            onClick={DeleteAccount}
                            className={styles.registerBtn}
                        />
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </>
    );
}

export default AccountsCompo;
```

I just used the developer tools and console.log() to see if the request was being received, and had the backend part person look at the code together. And ChatGPT 4 was also used.
ChatGPT 4 said that there are points to upgrade the code, but there are no errors.